# How can I conditionally replace all values in a column depending on cell content?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe and I would like to replace all the cells that contain the string "low" with just "low". Could anyone help me please? Below is my dataframe.

I have tried to this with replace and loc:

```
df.loc[df['Stock'].str.contains('low').replace(to_replace=None,value="low",regex=True)]
```

however this gives me a regex error. I have tried reading the documentation for replace too, but havent gotten much further as it wouldnt be an exact match that I would be replacing.

I have tried it by getting a list about what contains "low" but that hasnt been working either:

```
list(df['Stock'])
['low stock', 'low stck', 'low stock', 'in stock', 'in stock', 'instock', 'lowstock', 'low', 'low on stock', 'in stock', 'in stock a lot', 'low_ on stock', 'low', 'low_on_stock ', ' lowstock', 'in stock', 'instock']

list(df.loc[df['Stock'].str.contains('low')])
['Company', 'Country', 'Stock']

list(df['Stock'].str.contains('low'))
[True, True, True, False, False, False, True, True, True, False, False, True, True, True, True, False, False]
```

```
        Company Country           Stock
0      Michelin     USA       low stock
1   Continental     USA        low stck
2   Continental     USA       low stock
3      Michelin     USA        in stock
4      Michelin     USA        in stock
5      Michelin     USA         instock
6      Michelin     USA        lowstock
7      Michelin     USA             low
8      Michelin     USA    low on stock
9       Pirelli     USA        in stock
10     Goodyear     USA  in stock a lot
11     Michelin     USA   low_ on stock
12  Continental     USA             low
13     Michelin     USA   low_on_stock 
14  Continental     USA        lowstock
15     Michelin     USA        in stock
16     Michelin     USA         instock
```

Comment: `list(df.loc[df['Stock'].str.contains('low')])` returns the **column names**!

Comment: [Boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing). Probably best to work through the whole Indexing and selecting data section. Indexing and selection methods can be used for assignments (on the left-hand-side).

Answer (score 1):

[`.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) is the correct method for this.

You can either assign the values directly (like grymlin shows), or use [`.mask()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) which is more flexible as it accepts the argument `inplace` (by default `False`) and can be chained:

```py
df['Stock'].mask(df['Stock'].str.contains('low'), 'low')
```

Comment: this worked, thank you so much!! I set it to 
df['Stock'] = df['Stock'].mask(df['Stock'].str.contains('low'), 'low')
and now its done, thanks again!

Comment: @messingjuri, or you can pass `inplace=True` like this: `df['Stock'].mask(df['Stock'].str.contains('low'), 'low', inplace=True)`

Answer (score 1):

this should work:

```
df.loc[df["Stock"].str.contains("low"), "Stock"] = "low"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `lambda` with a condition for such operation

```py
>>> df_stock
                 stock
0        low stock
1         low stck
2        low stock
3         in stock
4         in stock
5          instock
6         lowstock
7              low
8     low on stock
9         in stock
10  in stock a lot
11   low_ on stock
12             low
13   low_on_stock
14        lowstock
15        in stock
16         instock
```

```py
>>> df_stock['stock'].apply(lambda x: 'low' if 'low' in x else x)
0                low
1                low
2                low
3           in stock
4           in stock
5            instock
6                low
7                low
8                low
9           in stock
10    in stock a lot
11               low
12               low
13               low
14               low
15          in stock
16           instock
Name: stock, dtype: object
```